# Try to Pause video during streaming using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there any ffmpeg command to pause video during streaming. I tried to pause/resume using Playing keys ('P').Please suggest how can i integrate these key or any command in shell script.

Comment: Please add some code for others,

Comment: Are you sending or receiving the stream?

Comment: receiving some commands from server and use these command for streaming